# Establish secure channel to domain workstations to transmit password in clear text

Tags: windows, security, remote-access

I want to use some command line tools for remote administration of Microsoft domain workstations, however some of them transmit the credentials in clear text.

Is there a command line utility I can use to establish an secure connection prior to using those tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you application layer sends sensitive data in plain text I see 2 possible workarounds:

1. Remote to the target system using a secure connection and issue commands there. Not always feasible, because you'd need to have needed tools installed on the target systems.
2. Employ encryption on a lower level of a stack. This could take a form of VPN between the systems involved. Probably a lot of hassle to configure it for all systems you'd want to connect to.

There's also a 3rd possibility. Replace your utility with a tool that pays attention to security and privacy.

Comment: Can you recommend some secure connection tools?

Comment: Windows isn't my speciality, so I do not know any tools first hand, and would rather refrain from recommending any specific solution.